# Are low probability events due to chance?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

My question is based on this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1545167/969781). But I have stated it with some simplifications.

Assume there is an city where some bad people are dropping bombs. A survey reported that each square kilometre of the area gets $1$ bomb dropped everyday.

A person on an unlucky day reports that in their area there were $6$ bombs dropped on that day. Now first we had to calculate the probability of this happening which I conveniently did using the Poisson distribution.

Next the question asked whether **this particular event was a coincidence or not a coincidence**. I am not comfortable with the word coincidence, so I switch it for the word chance.
Then I ask, was the unfortunate event by chance?

Now I think that it is a very low probability event. And one could say that the enemy was targeting that area and thus intentionally dropped more bombs there. Or probably the bomb launching system had a systematic error and due to which more than average bombs were dropped there. And one would suspect that this was an event not by chance. It was schematic.

My question is would one be wrong in following this argument and concluding that the event were not by chance and thus not a coincidence?

I understand from a comment on the linked question that the event follows a binomial distribution, but as long as the numbers are close enough my question is the same.

Comment: I understand from a comment on the linked question that the event follows a binomial distribution, but as long as the numbers are close enough my question is the same.

Comment: Welcome. It is good to edit your post, and not good to leave comments that are easy to miss. Comments are for other users to make notes on your post, or for you to reply to other people

Comment: If you calculate something, (with the Poisson distribution), and if it is relevant to your question, I advise you edit in your calculations using "MathJax" (use `$` dollar signs to render equations nicely), e.g. the Poisson distribution is written like this: `$$P(k;\lambda)=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\cdot e^{-\lambda}$$`, which renders as this: $$P(k;\lambda)=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\cdot e^{-\lambda}$$

Comment: if you understand probability theory as a way to model reality basic in statistical evidence then there is no difference between an schematic attack and a "random" attack because both will follow a probability distribution. Depending in the statistics of the attacks you can model the fall of bombs with some probability distribution or other, the expected utility of this probability model to predict new attacks will depend on many factors, and just reality will show how accurate is this model

Comment: I suppose you have calculated as 0.06% the probability that a given square kilometre on a given day suffers more than five bombings. But it depends on the number of areas and the number of days under consideration, the probability that *some* area on *some* day will suffer more than five bombings. Anyway I guess this is a problem about [hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing).